# encrypted password to plain text password Using 3DES algorithm

Tags: encryption, passwords, text, algorithm

How to convert encrypted passwod to  plain text password? 
please any one give some idea for this.

I have a AES256 algorithm as given below. I need 3DES algorithm .

```
Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);
String crypt = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cryptoKey);
system.debug('crypt::'+crypt);

Blob data = Blob.valueOf('Test data to encrypted');
String csvBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(data);
system.debug('csvBody::'+csvBody);  

Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, data);
String encryptedDataString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
system.debug('encryptedDataString::'+encryptedDataString);

Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, encryptedData);
String decryptedDataString = decryptedData.toString();
system.debug('decryptedDataString::'+decryptedDataString);
```

Comment: I hope you're not working with actual passwords. You should never decrypt those, and you should never be-able to decrypt those.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use any algorithm not provided by the platform. The currently supported algorithms are:

1. AES128
2. AES192
3. AES256

If you plan on encrypting/decrypting anything in Apex Code, it needs to be in one of those algorithms.

If you're dealing with passwords, please make sure you read [Securely Coding Storing Secrets](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Storing_Secrets) to make sure you're not violating security recommendations. Ideally, you shouldn't be making passwords recoverable at all, but sometimes it's necessary. If possible, consider using a digest algorithm instead; this would let you verify that a password is correct or not without exposing the password.